# cbar = False removing seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to create a seaborn heatplot. I want to grey out specific values, which I can do, but I don't want a colorbar for the greyed out values. However, whenever I try `cbar = False`, it removes the entire heatmap. Is there a way to remove the colorbar but keep the heatmap?

This gives me the result I want, but it adds a colorbar.

```
sns.heatmap(no_data, vmin = 1, cmap = 'Greys', 
                    linewidths = 0.1, ax=ax[0])
    sns.heatmap(no_data, vmin = 1, cmap = 'Greys', 
                    linewidths = 0.1, ax=ax[1])
    
sns.heatmap(adc_data, mask = data_mask, vmin = min_adc, cmap = 'plasma', 
                    linewidths = 0.1, ax=ax[0], linecolor='darkgray', cbar_kws={'label': 'ADC'})
sns.heatmap(time_data, mask = data_mask, vmin = min_time, cmap = 'plasma', 
                    linewidths = 0.1, ax=ax[1], linecolor='darkgray', cbar_kws={'label': 'Time'})
```

[sns heatmap with two colorbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Pm4.png)

If I add cbar = False, it gets rid of the grey plot entirely.

```
sns.heatmap(no_data, vmin = 1, cmap = 'Greys', cbar = False,
                    linewidths = 0.1, ax=ax[0])
    sns.heatmap(no_data, vmin = 1, cmap = 'Greys', cbar = False,
                    linewidths = 0.1, ax=ax[1])
    
sns.heatmap(adc_data, mask = data_mask, vmin = min_adc, cmap = 'plasma', 
                    linewidths = 0.1, ax=ax[0], linecolor='darkgray', cbar_kws={'label': 'ADC'})
sns.heatmap(time_data, mask = data_mask, vmin = min_time, cmap = 'plasma', 
                    linewidths = 0.1, ax=ax[1], linecolor='darkgray', cbar_kws={'label': 'Time'})
```

[sns heatmap with no colorbar or grey values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r1gd.png)

EDIT:
Here's an example:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))

adc_data = random.randint(50, size=(21, 21))
no_data = np.arange(441).reshape((21, 21))

for i in range(len(adc_data)):
    for j in range(len(adc_data[i])):
        if adc_data[i][j] < 25:
            no_data[i][j] = 1
        else:
            no_data[i][j] = 0

data_mask = adc_data < 25
data_mask2 = no_data == 0

sns.heatmap(no_data, mask = data_mask2, cmap = 'Greys', linewidths = 0.5, cbar = True)
sns.heatmap(adc_data, mask = data_mask, cmap = 'plasma', linewidths = 0.5,
            linecolor='gray', cbar_kws={'label': 'ADC'})
```

If cbar = False, the grey plot dissappears.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: It's hard to guess what is happening without reproducible test data.  It is hard to grasp how the two plots can come from exactly the same data and from the code shown.  Also, `vmin=1` would give a colorbar starting at `1`, not at `0.9`. Anyway, my guess would be something else has gone wrong in code that isn't shown, as `cbar=False` really shouldn't make disappear the heatmap.